# Correct way to initialize kendo widgets inside template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

Im inserting an widget within template like this:

```
<script id="example-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">           
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-expand="expandHandler">           
        <h3>#= example #</h3>           
    </div>            
</script>
```

But the widget is does not initialize, just show as plain html.
Some people suggest to use kendo.mobile.init and it works, but looks like a hack. This method is not at least documented.

My question is: what can I do to properly initialize widgets inside template?

Complete example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://da7xgjtj801h2.cloudfront.net/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://da7xgjtj801h2.cloudfront.net/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://da7xgjtj801h2.cloudfront.net/2015.2.624/js/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- view -->
  <div id="foo" 
       data-role="view" 
       data-show="onShow"
       data-model="viewModel">
    
    <div id="bar">
    </div>
    
  </div>  
  
  <!-- template -->
  <script id="collapsible-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
       
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-expand="expandHandler">
            
            <h3>
                #= title #
            </h3>
            
            <table>
            
                <tr>
                    <td>Line 1:</td>
                    <td>#= line1 #</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Line 2:</td>
                    <td>#= line2 #</td>
                </tr>
                
            </table>
            
        </div>
        
  </script>
   
  
  <script>
  
    var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();
    
    var data = [
              {"title": "title1", "line1": "line 1", "line2": "line 21"},
              {"title": "title2", "line1": "line 12", "line2": "line 22"}
            ];
    
    function onShow(){          

      var template = kendo.template($("#collapsible-template").html());
      $("#bar").html(kendo.render(template, data));          
     
    }
    
    function expandHandler(){
      console.log("expand");
    }
    
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Reading  [docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/data-attribute-initialization#initialize-in-given-element) again, realized that `kendo.bind($("#bar"), {}, kendo.mobile.ui)` is the right way to do.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you do that mvvm way, go on with this initializing it on the javascript instead if it is okay

See the example :

```js
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();
    
    var data = [
              {"title": "title1", "line1": "line 1", "line2": "line 21"},
              {"title": "title2", "line1": "line 12", "line2": "line 22"}
            ];
    
    function expandHandler(){
      console.log("expand");
    }
    
    function onShow(){          

      var template = kendo.template($("#collapsible-template").html());
      $("#bar").html(kendo.render(template, data));          
     
      $(".test").kendoMobileCollapsible({
         expand: expandHandler
      })
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <!-- view -->
  <div id="foo" 
       data-role="view" 
       data-show="onShow"
       data-model="viewModel">
    
    <div id="bar">
    </div>
    
  </div>  
  
  <!-- template -->
  <script id="collapsible-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
       
        <div class="test">
            
            <h3>
                #= title #
            </h3>
            
            <table>
            
                <tr>
                    <td>Line 1:</td>
                    <td>#= line1 #</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Line 2:</td>
                    <td>#= line2 #</td>
                </tr>
                
            </table>
            
        </div>
        
  </script>
   
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this works too. Im thinking if there is a way to render the template  before binds occour, so all widgets would be initilizated in proper way.